# Guava multimap using Random Access file?

Tags: java, io, guava, bigdata

I have a file of Integer[]s that is too large to put in memory.  I would like to search for all arrays with a last member of x and use them in other code.  Is there a way to use Guava's multimap to do this, where x is the key and stored in memory and the Integer[] is the value and that is stored on disk?  In this scenario, the keys are not unique, but key-value pairs are unique.  Reading of this multimap (assuming that it's possible) will be concurrent.  I'm also open to suggestions of other ways to approach this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class representing an array on disk (based on its index in the file of arrays), let's call it `FileBackedIntArray`, and put instances of that as the values of a `HashMultimap<Integer, FileBackedIntArray>`:

```
public class FileBackedIntArray {
    // Index of the array in the file of arrays
    private final int index;
    private final int lastElement;

    public FileBackedIntArray(int index, int lastElement) {
        this.index = index;
        this.lastElement = lastElement;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public int[] readArray() {
        // Read the file and deserialize the array at the associated index
        return smth;
    }

    public int getLastElement() {
        return lastElement;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        } else if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        return index == ((FileBackedIntArray) o).index;
    }
}
```

*Do you actually need an `Integer[]` and not an `int[]`, by the way (i.e. you can have `null` values)?* As you've said in the comments, you don't really need an `Integer[]`, so using `ints`s everywhere will avoid boxing/unboxing and will save a lot of space since you appear to have lots of them. Hopefully you don't have a huge number of possible values for the last element (x).

You then create an instance for each array and read the last element to put it the `Multimap` without keeping the array around. Populating the `Multimap` needs to be either sequential or protected with a lock if concurrent, but reading can be concurrent without any protection. You could even create an `ImmutableMultimap` once the `HashMultimap` has been populated, to guard against any modification, a safe practice in a concurrent environment.

Comment: I checked the program and no I don't need Integer[], int[] will work.

Comment: @blue OK, I edited the answer to take that into account. But is it helpful anyway?